# Command contains unregnized phrase/keywords

Tags: vb6, foxpro

I have a vb6 project and i need to update a visual foxpro table from a recordset.My issue is when i try to update the table i get error msg:Command contains unregnized phrase/keywords.My problem is situated where the date field is concern.I dont know if i written the last portion of the code right.Here is my code:

```
rs2.Open "update transac set no_ot_1_5 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt1") & ", no_ot_2_0 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt2") & ", no_ot_3_0" _
& "= " & rs1.Fields("ovt3") & "where code = '" & rs1.Fields("emp_code") & "and transac.date = & trans.txtend &", cn1, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the solution from G Mastros is still not complete, it may be due to incorrect data type of a "Date" field. you may need to change to

transac.date = CTOD('" & trans.txtend &"') "

as if you are sending in a text string, but the date is of a DATE type field, you'll need to have it converted to a VFP recognized function... CTOD() is Convert Character String to a Date.

Comment: Thanks a lot DRapp your solution work!I've been trying since 2 days thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rs2.Open "update transac set no_ot_1_5 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt1") & ", no_ot_2_0 = " & rs1.Fields("ovt2") & ", no_ot_3_0" _
& "= " & rs1.Fields("ovt3") & " where code = '" & rs1.Fields("emp_code") & "' and transac.date = '" & trans.txtend &"'", cn1, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
```

It looks like you were missing a space before the WHERE keyword and you missed a single-quote after emp_code. It also looks like you had a problem with transac date.